# how to display image upon clicking the button and slide the image option by swiping in the particular direction in android studio?

Tags: android, image, swipe, slide, floating

I have created a float button in Android Studio

[image]

After I click the image, the add floating button should be disabled and the 3 images should be displayed. One images have to selected from the images displayed horizontally just like in the image below. If i have to select the image in the right then i have to the right to position the image in the center and select the image

[image]

And after choosing the appropriate image it should be back to displaying floating button like in the first image.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have provided an example outline of what you are trying to do.  You will have to add a lot more code, but this will get you started.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private boolean cupImageClicked = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    //initialize and set up imageViews and button.

    //listener for button.
    mFloatingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mFloatingButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageView_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    //example click listener for an image.
    cupImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (cupImageClicked) {
                //this will execute when cupImage is already in the center
                //gather whatever info you need from that clicked image.

                imageView_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imageView_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imageView_3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mFloatingButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE;

            } else {
                //here you will need to move the cupImage to the center and
                //  move the center imageView to the left.
                cupImageClicked = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```